# its possible compile another java code in java when I click a button?

Tags: java, compilation

Im trying to use this command but is very slow

How I could compile use java code

I execute this code for  2 minutes but not compile in this time

```
 JButton cn= new JButton("push me3");
cn.setBounds( 0,0,295,20 );
f.add(cn);  
 cn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {

      @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)      {
       String title =hellopanelx40.getText();
     try {
         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac example.java     ");
        p.waitFor();





      } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }

 catch (IOException e2) {

 }


   }

   });
```

PLease help me

Comment: Please don't post "junk" or repeated text with your question. You've done this to get around the requirement to include adequate explanation with your question, and your attempt to get around this is not playing fair or nice to the volunteers of this site. Please add more text explaining your problem in greater detail. Also, why do you think that there is a faster way to compile the code? One issue I see is that of threading, that you're doing all of this on the Swing event thread, and that you should be doing it in a background thread such as a SwingWorker.

Comment: What do you mean by "slow"?  Do you mean that the program never finishes or that it finishes but takes an excessive amount of time(when compared to a normal command line operation doing the same thing)?

Comment: I use for 2 minutes but not finish I dont know If this finish .

Comment: The `p.waitFor()` will return when it has finished, and will give you a return value as well. Again, do this in a SwingWorker, and handle that return value. One question: does the code work? Does it compile the Java class? I notice that you run it without declaring a classpath

Comment: yes this code works  I  was use this code for execute JAR FILE ; but now I need use this same code for compile .JAVA files

Comment: but when I try to compile another java code take so much time and I dont know if this finish

Comment: I solve this using a bash script with javac code and works